# Error to pass URL variable from index page to an autenticated page without change value

Tags: javascript, php, variables, url

I did a searching in the similar questions, but I did not find a solution for my problem.

I would like to pass part of the URL from the index page to another function that is called if the user is autenticated. I can print the url variable in the next page, before the authentication. But since, the URL changes when the user is autenticated, I am getting a blank. How do I keep the value in the other page after the URL change?

In my index.php I call a js function that gey the course number when the page loads:

`<body onload="myFunction()">`

The myFunction is js code in data.js file that get part of the URL:

```
  const url = location.href;

  const urlCourse=url.split('=')[1];

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = urlCourse.toString(8);
}
```

In the callCourses.php, I have:

```
const course='<p id=demo></p>';
 echo course; // It works!


if ($GLOBALS['authenticated'] ) { //here the URL will change because the user is now authenticated

echo course; // Error does not get the course number.
```

Answer (score 2):

If the url is changed after authentication and if you have no access to changing that url, you will need to store that variable in one of the following places:

**On the Server**

- Cookies
- Session Cookies

```php
// Before authentication
$_SESSION['courseNumber'] = getCourseNumberFromURL();
...
// In authenticated
$courseNumber = $_SESSION['courseNumber'];
```

**Web Browser**

- Local Storage
- Session Storage

```js
// Before authentication
localStorage.set('courseNumber', getCourseNumberFromURL())
...
// After Authentication
const courseNumber = localStorage.get('courseNumber')
```

**Edit - Expanded Answer**
So, I think some clarification is needed here. PHP and JavaScript can't actually communicate with each other in the way I think you are understanding. You can use PHP to generate dynamic scripts, but once the html has been sent to the user, PHP can no longer interact with or manipulate that page. This means you can't access a JavaScript variable via PHP.

If we need to send JavaScript data over to our server, we perform one of two actions:

1. Create a custom form and send it to a PHP endpoint.
2. Make an XMLHttpRequest.

For 2, I recommend looking into fetch, which is highly supported in all modern browsers. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

With that explanation out of the way, here is what I recommend doing for your case:

```php
<?php
// Whatever you had before

// Store the courseNumber if we haven't already
if (!$_SESSION['courseNumber']) {
  $_SESSION['courseNumber'] = $_GET['courseNumber'];
}
// More junk
// Now, let's check if authenticated:
if ($GLOBALS['authenticated'] ) {
  // We are! Let's echo the courseNumber
  echo $_SESSION['courseNumber'];
  // Or, if you need to do it in a tag, try this:
  // This directly inserts the data as the page is being generated to send by PHP
  echo "<p id='demo'>".$_SESSION['courseNumber']."</p>";
  // Or do this if you have to have the JavaScript insert the value for some reason
  echo "<p id='demo'></p>";
  echo "<script>document.querySelector('#demo').innerText = '" . $_SESSION['courseNumber'] . "'</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried the solution on the server, but does not print the course number. Are there something wrong with my  function? ```function getCourseNumberFromURL(){
     $course='<p id=demo></p>';
     return $course;
    
}
```

Comment: @Maple, your function returns html and does not access the course number. You should be able to access the query parameter in pHp with something like this:

`$_SESSION['courseNumber'] = $_GET[$queryParam];`

where `$queryParam` is equal to the thing before the = in the url.

Comment: $_GET[$queryParam] works too, but I still not able to get the course number after the papge load and the user becomes authenticated.

Comment: I tried to use the webbrowser solution, but when I try to pass the contant to a php variable it get NULL. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Maple, I highly recommend reading first my explanation and solution, but then second doing a deep dive into PHP, JavaScript, and how to really use both of them.